# Searching for multiple terms in the streaming API using tweepy and knowing which one hits?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to use tweepy to build a dataset of tweets. Right now, I have the stream running for a single search term but I would like to use the library to search for different queries at the same time. I know I am able to supply the `twitterStream.filter` function with a list instead of just the "Disney" term, however I am not sure how I can see which tweet is a result to which term returned in this case.

What would be a good extension of the following code to search for `["Disney", "Pandabears", "Polarbears"]` instead of just `"Disney"` and know which query returned the hit?

I can think of two ways to do this in principle:

1: Search the resulting tweet for the search terms and tag them accordingly. However, this doesn't really solve the problem as a tweet might contain two of the search terms. [Described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519351/tweepy-tracking-multiple-terms)

2: Run as many of the streams as there are search terms. However, I'm not sure the API allows the same app to have multiple active streams at once?

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time

ckey = "secret"
csecret="secret"
atoken="secret"
asecret="secret"
searchterm = "Disney"

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0] 
            saveThis = str(time.time())+"::%::"+tweet    
            saveFile = open("tweets.csv", "a")
            saveFile.write(saveThis)
            saveFile.write("\n")
            saveFile.close()
            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print "Failed on data", str(e)
            time.sleep(10) 
            return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
        time.sleep(5)
        return True # Don't kill the stream

try:
    auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
    auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
    twitterStream.filter(track=[searchterm])
except Exception:
    print "Failed in auth or streaming"
```

Is there a "good" way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't run as many streams as terms from the same app because of the API limitations, you would need to do that on different machines with different keys. But if you did you would still get the same tweet on multiple streams if a tweet contains more than one search term. What you need to decide is how you want to handle this cases and then write the corresponding logic using the terms list. You could discard them if they contain more than one term, tag them multiple times or set a tagging priority and only use one tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen to go with option 1 and run a single stream with multiple search terms, checking each tweet for matches manually...

```
tweet = "I am a tweet"
terms = ["am","tweet"]
matches = []
for i, term in enumerate(terms):
                    if( term.lower() in tweet.lower() ):
                        matches.append(i)

matches
Out: [0, 1]
```

...and adding the resulting matches list in the the object returned by the stream listener. Of course, this results in a larger stram, increasing the hazard of being rate limited.